# ADODB.Connection (0x800A0E78)

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, connection-string

Original connectionstring whitch working on MSSQL 2000:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=XXXXXXXX; Initial Catalog=IntranetApps; Data Source=MS; Use Procedure for Prepare=1; Auto Translate=True; Packet Size=4096; Workstation ID=datawriter; Password=XXXXXXXX';

New connectionstring which not working on MSSQL 2008:

> Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=PR-NB-CIS011\SQLEXPRESS;Database=IntranetApps;Uid=XXXXXXXX;Pwd=XXXXXXXX;

I tryed change provider to SQLNCLI10.1, without provider, ...

Once in past i solved same problem, but hell, i don't remember it now. I thing that there was needed install some provider, but i can find nothing about it now.

There is code witch throw exception:

```
this.connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    this.connection.ConnectionString = this.conString;
    try {
        this.connection.Open;
    }
    catch(e){
        Response.write("Chyba pri pripojeni na db.");
        return false; // pokud dojde k chybe pri pripojovani k databazi, pak fce vraci false, jinak true
    }
```

Comment: You are implying a query error "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" but you've added connection string information...

Comment: ADODB.Connection (0x800A0E78)
Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

Comment: So, connection string is OK and there is different problem?

Comment: Yes. From the error message it sounds like you are trying to access data in a recordset without first calling its' `.Open()` method. Could you post your full code and error message with the line number the error is on.

Comment: After call Open, there is exception: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server neexistuje nebo byl odepřen přístup." (I didn't find exact localization, it means: "Server not exist or acces denied.")
number: -2147467259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this really is a connection string problem, you should:

1. study the [basics](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)
2. create a zero length "whatever.udl" file and start it from command line; you can then twiddle the parameters, test the connection, and paste the connection string from the clipboard
3. try `";Data Source=PR-NB-CIS011\SQLEXPRESS;"` instead of `";Server=PR-NB-CIS011\SQLEXPRESS;"`

Comment: It seems that they are synonyms. It throw same exception. On connectionstrings.com are using sometimes Server and sometimes Data Source.

Comment: @Zdenek: Sorry. I included (3) because I tested it successfully and thought it worth a try. Did you experiment with (2)? I find the possibility to test assumptions interactively in a gui to be helpful. You may try other providers to test the accessibilty of your server/database to pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: I used whatever.udl connection string. Thanks. Problem was that I didn't know how work with it but now it's OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> After call Open, there is exception: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server neexistuje nebo byl odepřen přístup." (I didn't find exact localization, it means: "Server not exist or acces denied.") number: -2147467259

In this case it appears the server specified in your connection string does not exist, is not running or the user account you've provided doesn't have sufficient permissions.

Things to try:

1) Your connection string is not correctly formatted for SQL Express 2008, try this:

```
Server=PR-NB-CIS011\SQLEXPRESS;Database=IntranetApps;User Id=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX;
```

2) When you open Management Studio, try and connect with the username and password of your connection string. This sometimes makes it quicker and easier to find and trace permissions issues.

3) If you're logging in with a SQL server user account, make sure you have SQL server and windows authentication enabled. To do this, in SQL Management Studio, right click the server, Properties, and on the Security tab, check 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode'

Comment: I tryed this and I can't connect with this user. 

I created him from my administrator account, after that i set password and read/write for IntrenetApps database. If I try browse server to select IntranetApps db and connect, there is error Login failed for user 'XXXXXXXX' (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: Have a look in the event log of your server to find out the state of the 18456 error - it will give you the exact problem. More info at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx