# C++ and ADODB : Com error 0x800a0e78

Tags: c++, sql, visual-c++, com

I have a C++ library that calls a stored procedure in MSSQL database using ADODB. Everything works fine on development database. But on test database, I am getting Com error 0x800a0e78: This option is not allowed if an object is closed.

The code looks like

```
ADODB::_CommandPtr cmd = NULL;
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr rs = NULL;

CHECKHR(cmd.CreateInstance( __uuidof( ADODB::Command) ));
cmd->ActiveConnection = m_connexion;
cmd->CommandText = "my_stored_procedure";
cmd->CommandType = ADODB::adCmdStoredProc;

CHECKHR(cmd->Parameters->Refresh());

//input param
cmd->Parameters->GetItem(paramIndex)->put_Value(paramValue);

// output param
cmd->Parameters->GetItem(paramIndex)->PutDirection(ADODB::adParamOutput);

rs = cmd->Execute( NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdStoredProc);

while(! rs->ADO_EOF ) { ...
```

rs->ADO_EOF is where it crashes the program if I use the test database.

note: The stored procedure is same in both the databases and returns same data.
There is one more flow where another SP is called. It works well with the test database. The problem appears only with this particular SP.

I tend to think that it is not a code issue because it works with development database. But I can consistently reproduce the problem with test database.

Please suggest of next actions I should take to resolve this issue

UPDATE

Due to some miracle this C++ exception has gone away after 1 day. But it is so very slow that the execution almost always times out. I do not know how to justify this behavior

UPDATE: 2013-07-18

After so much time, the error has appeared again. This time with development DB with the same SP

```
[Com error 0x800a0e78 : Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
```

on the same line

```
 while(! rs->ADO_EOF ) {
```

in rs I can see a memory address pointing to ADODB recordset object. But rs->ADO_EOF is generating the said error

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADODB.Connection (0x800A0E78)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988843/adodb-connection-0x800a0e78)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the while line, what does rs evaluate to? Is it still NULL? Is it a valid recordset object? Is the object full of data?

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy It is not null. It appears to have data

Comment: @Preet How do I solve the problem ?

Comment: @preet or rather how do I detect that it is the reason to start with 
?

Comment: What type of "crash"? Is it a c++ exception?

Comment: @Simon yes, a c++ exception. Com error 0x800a0e78: This option is not allowed if an object is closed.

Comment: Is the procedure supposed to send back something?

Comment: @Simon Yes it outputs 6 recordsets.